# Asus Am604g as ethernet router

Tags: router, ethernet

I used Asus AM604-g as ADSL router. 
Not long ago I've moved from ADSL to LAN. Is it possible to use this device as ethernet router (I connect to LAN using VPN). If yes, how I need to configure it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little clearer?  ADSL is a WAN technology, LAN is not...do you mean you switched to cable? Or some other internet provider?

Comment: Yes, early I used ADSL ISP. This router has one socket for phone line, and four for ethernet cable. Now I use ethernet ISP and have one ethernet cable, curently pluged into my PC. I want to connect it to am604g (somehow) and share this internet connection via ethernet and wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if it is possible.  The "internet" side of the ADSL router does some stuff that you need (DHCP client, NAT) and a bunch of stuff that you don't (ADSL translation, likely PPPoE authentication).  You **might** be able to turn off PPPoE and make a cable to connect the RJ14 internet jack to the RJ11 on the Asus.

As I see it, you have several of options, listed in order of my preference.  See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/72160/need-prosumer-router-firewall-vpn-vlan-nat-advice) for a discussion about home router/connectivity options.

1- Get a "standard" broadband router.  They are inexpensive, easy to setup, and just work.  I have had good luck with Linksys and Netgear.

2- Roll your own router on a spare PC with two NICs.  I would use [Astaro](http://www.astaro.com/our_products/astaro_security_gateway/software_appliance), although other options are noted on the question I linked above.  You can use the Asus as a switch and wireless AP behind it.

3- Plug a PC with wired and wireless into the ethernet internet jack and get it working.  Then set it up to share the internet connection, and use the Asus switch capabilities to connect the other computers to the gateway.  THIS IS A KLUDGE .. I would not do it permanently.

Comment: thanks, tomjedrz! the only reason I asked it, is that this router is quite good (supports wifi) and I have paid for it about 80$ not long ago, so I want to reuse it with my new ISP :)